# Why can't I install "forecast" package in RStudio?

Tags: r, installation, forecasting

I was trying to install the "forecast" package and had trouble installing. I tried install.packages("forecast") and get this error message:

```
*Installing package into ‘C:/Users/DT217/Documents/R/win-library/3.1’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
  有二进制版本（将被安装），但源代码版本是后来的:
         binary source
forecast    5.8    5.9
also installing the dependencies ‘zoo’, ‘RcppArmadillo’
trying URL 'http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.1/zoo_1.7-11.zip'
Warning in install.packages :
cannot open: HTTP status was '404 Not Found'
Error in download.file(url, destfile, method, mode = "wb", ...) : 
cannot open URL 'http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.1/zoo_1.7-11.zip'
Warning in install.packages :
download of package ‘zoo’ failed
trying URL 'http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.1/RcppArmadillo_0.4.600.4.0.zip'
Warning in install.packages :
cannot open: HTTP status was '404 Not Found'
Error in download.file(url, destfile, method, mode = "wb", ...) : 
cannot open URL'http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.1/RcppArmadillo_0.4.600.4.0.zip'
Warning in install.packages :
download of package ‘RcppArmadillo’ failed
trying URL'http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.1/forecast_5.8.zip'
Warning in install.packages :
cannot open: HTTP status was '404 Not Found'
Error in download.file(url, destfile, method, mode = "wb", ...) : 
cannot open URL 'http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.1/forecast_5.8.zip'
Warning in install.packages :
download of package ‘forecast’ failed*
```

I tried to open the URL given in the error and can't open it. I also tried installing "zoo" package and got similar error. However, I was able to install some other package, so some packages are working.

Here are the info about the version of the RStudio I am using:

```
$platform
[1] "x86_64-w64-mingw32"
$arch
[1] "x86_64"
$os
[1] "mingw32"
$system
[1] "x86_64, mingw32"
$status
[1] ""
$major
[1] "3"
$minor
[1] "1.3"
$year
[1] "2015"
$month
[1] "03"
$day
[1] "09"
$`svn rev`
[1] "67962"
$language
[1] "R"
$version.string
[1] "R version 3.1.3 (2015-03-09)"
$nickname
[1] "Smooth Sidewalk"*
```

Here's a post with similar questions. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Sophie

Comment: Very interesting.  It seems your RStudio is using bad URLs to find dependencies.  I had the same problem you did.

Comment: I'm still using R 3.1.2, but I've just tried installing forecast from the RStudio mirror (which generally is preferable to other mirrors) and it installed forecast 5.9 (note the different version number to your attempt) without problems.

Comment: zoo is also at a higher version number now.

Comment: @Roland Thank you for your reply! Seems like I chose a bad mirror? I'm sorry, but which mirror are you refering to? I thought mirrors are categorized in region?

Comment: RStudio's CRAN mirror [is special](http://blog.rstudio.org/2013/06/10/rstudio-cran-mirror/). My comment meant to say that you should not see attempted download of older versions. Are you by chance somehow using packrat?

Comment: @Roland I'm not using packrat. I think everything goes well now after I changed the CRAN mirror.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest fix to your problem would be to try selecting a different CRAN mirror for downloading and installing the `forecast` package.  You can manually select a mirror by choosing:

```
Packages -> Set CRAN mirror...
```

I just ran `install.packages("forecast")` using the Singapore mirror (as I live there), and I had no problem.

If you must continue to use your current mirror, then you will have to figure out which dependencies cannot be downloaded and you must obtain them manually from somewhere.

Comment: Hi Tim, thank you for your quick reply! I installed the package manually, but I will definitely try selecting a different mirror.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem . after the command :

```
install.packages("forecast_5.9.tgz")
```

appears warning:
    Warning in install.packages :
      package 'forecast_5.9.tgz' is not available (for R version 3.1.2)

the below command works

```
install.packages("forecast")
```

also installed other related packages.

Best Swapnil